# How do i put two Jquery functions together?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My Problem is that i have two function who does the same thing but for different objects

here is the code.

```
$('body').on('click', '.toogle1', function() {
    $('body').find('.buttonshow').slideToggle(300);
    $('body').find('.buttonshow ').val(title);
});

$('body').on('click', '.toogle', function() {
    $('body').find('.htmlshow').slideToggle(400);
});
```

Comment: But they don't do the same things... ?

Comment: And what have you tried? Where is your problem?

Comment: ***"who does the same thing together"*** - Your code disagrees with your statements

Answer (score 1):

```
$('body').on('click', '.toggle, .toggle1', function(){ ... });
```

This would result in the logic firing for any child that has class 'toggle' or 'toggle1'.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know your html code but where you have class `toggle` add 2nd class `toggle1` so final class will be `class="toggle toggle1"` and then:

```
$('body').on('click', '.toogle1', function() {
    $('body').find('.buttonshow').slideToggle(300);
    $('body').find('.buttonshow ').val(title);
    $('body').find('.htmlshow').slideToggle(400);
});
```

But if you have different CSS in this classes, use another answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a function that you will use instead of the anonimous function you're passing at the end:

```
function toggleElement(selector, ms){
   selector.slideToggle(ms);
}
```

And then, you simply apply it to your jQuery

```
$('body').on('click', '.toogle1', function(){
     toggleElement($('.buttonshow'), 300);
     // Then, the rest of your logic that differs
});
```

So basically, this is how you use a function that does the same thing while adding other logic, the best way is to create a basic function that does the logic that will be repeated, and then, you procedurally write the rest of your logic that differs. This way, it is much easier to deal with.